# React JS, When clicked one option, other options are also being selected

Tags: reactjs

Below is Options component It generates bunch of options The problem is that when I click One option Others are also being selected. I know why this is happening but I couldnt solve it

```html
const InterestGenerator = () => {
  const interest_emojis = [
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
  ];

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    selected ? setSelected(false) : setSelected(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="interests_options">
      {interest_emojis.map((interest) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={`interest ${selected ? " interest_selected" : ""}`}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            {!selected && (
              <img
                className="interest_emoji"
                src={require("../assets/emoji_" + interest.name + ".png")}
                alt="comedy_emoji"
              />
            )}
            {selected && <DoneIcon />}
            <span>{interest.name}</span>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default InterestGenerator;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biQ00.png)

Comment: You have to track *which* option is selected (something that uniquely identifies the option), not just that *an* option is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see you have a single selected state in the component. Hence even if you click once it's set for everybody.
The solution would be to have a component each having their own state that is doing what you're doing and rendering a list of those components.

Something like this will work :

This is the solo component :

```
const interestEmojiComponent = ({name})=>{

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    selected ? setSelected(false) : setSelected(true);
  };
  return (
          <div
            className={`interest ${selected ? " interest_selected" : ""}`}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            {!selected && (
              <img
                className="interest_emoji"
                src={require("../assets/emoji_" + name + ".png")}
                alt="comedy_emoji"
              />
            )}
            {selected && <DoneIcon />}
            <span>{name}</span>
          </div>
        );
}
```

And this is the generator Component :

```
const InterestGenerator = () => {
  const interest_emojis = [
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
    { name: "Comedy" },
  ];

  return(
    <div className="interests_options">
       {interest_emojis.map((interest) => <InterestEmojiComponent name={interest.name}/>)}
    </div>
     )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using just one selected state for all options which lead to your unexpected behavior. The solution here is to keep the selected state for each option

```
const [interest_emojis, set_interest_emojis] = useState([
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false },
  { name: "Comedy", selected: false }
]);

const handleClick = (index) => {
  const arr = [...interest_emojis];
  arr[index].selected = !arr[index].selected;
  set_interest_emojis(arr);
};
```

Demo

[image: Edit shy-snow-dlx8i]